# mergerfs no longer accepting "threads=2" option

Tags: backup, utilities, rdiff-backup

I wrote my backup script to automatically combine two external drives into one with mergerfs so I could use the whole thing as a destination directory for rdiff-backup. However, when I tried to run it recently I get the error:

```
fuse: unknown option `threads=2'
```

The "threads" option appears in the [man pages](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/mergerfs/mergerfs.1.en.html) so I'm not sure what I'm missing here. For reference this is my current mergerfs command that's failing:

```
mergerfs -o use_ino,category.create=mfs,threads=2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What version? "mergerfs -V"? You should always use the latest release as found on the github release page.